# German long "o" vs. "au". Is there a rule?

Tags: historical-linguistics, vowels, germanic-languages, german, cognates

There are common words in Germanic languages that have a long "o" vowel in the stem, and which in modern German seem to be either "o" or "au" randomly.
Examples:

Dutch ROOD, Swedish RÖD, German ROT

DUTCH DOOD, Swedish DÖD, German TOT

but:
Dutch KOPEN, Swedish KÖPA, German KAUFEN

Dutch LOPEN, Swedish LOPP (noun), German LAUFEN

Is there a rule, or is it random?
And what is the reason (maybe high vs. low German)?

Danke!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Proto-Germanic (PG) the prototypes of all the four words had the diphthong /au/ in the root:

> rot < PG *raudaz
>
> tot < PG *daudaz
>
> kaufen < OHG noun **koufo** (“merchant”) < Latin **caupō** (“tradesman, shopkeeper”)
>
> laufen < PG *hlaupaną

During the transition from Proto-Germanic to Old High German the diphthong /au/ > /ô/ before /r/, /h/ and all dentals, otherwise /au/ > /ou/. Since in ***raudaz** and ***daudaz** the diphthong /au/ was before the dental /d/, /au/ > /ô/, in ***hlaupaną** it was before /p/, so this change didn't happen. The exact PG form the Latin **caupō** transformed into is unknown to me, anyway /au/ was not before a dental there, so Latin /au/ > OHG /ou/.

Dutch has /oː/ in all the four words, because in its ancestor language Old Saxon aka Old Low German, the Proto-Germanic diphthong /au/ consistently developed into a long vowel /oː/.

As for Swedish, I don't know Old Norse and the Scandinavian languages enough to comment competently on the vowel change they had, maybe someone else here can do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, do you mean "Old Saxon aka Old *Low* German"? Otherwise I don't understand that part :)

Comment: The ancestor of Dutch is actually Old Frankish or Old Low Franconian, but the point is valid nonetheless.

Comment: As for Swedish, it borrowed heavily from Hansa-Low German in the middle ages, so that may be an explanation.

Comment: @geodude - Sure, you're right, just a typo, corrected it.

Comment: @FedorSteeman Do you know what the cognates are in icelandic? I'm curious whether the Scandinavian words were taken from Low German or natively evolved from PG.

Comment: @YellowSky Clear then, thanks! Btw, do you maybe know also why in English they also differentiated (red, dead - same pronounciation despite spelling, vs cheap, leap)?

Comment: @geodude - Well, the PG *au > OE **eo**, all the 4 words had this **eo** in the Old English times. They split in the Middle English period, when in some of the words this **eo** got shortened to **e**, and in some other words it turned into **øː** > **eː**. This shortening was inconsistent according to some sources, or happened before _t, d, th_ acording to the others. Anyway, the ME **e** remained /e/ in ModE (red, dead), the ME **eː** became ModE /iː/ (cheap, leap). The shortening is mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology , just search for 'dead' on that page.

Comment: @geodude I don't know enough Icelandic, but I did hear that it's so conserved that modern people have little trouble understanding Old Norse texts. Continental Scandinavian, on the other hand, has been thoroughly shaped by Hansa Low German in vocabulary and syntax. I believe there are estimates that up to 40% of Danish vocabulary is derived from Low German. The situation for Swedish is probably similar.

Comment: @geodude A quick lookup on Icelandic gave me "hlaupa", interestingly enough...

Comment: @FedorSteeman and red is "rauđur". Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

“Rot” and “tot” have a long ō in Old High German, but “laufen” and “kaufen” have the diphthong ou in OHG. ō and ou merge in some languages, in others they go their separate ways.